# Touch sensor for a line drawn in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, graphics, opengl-es

I have a requirement to draw a line on a UIView in IOS with OpenGL ES. But the line that is drawn could be able to move anywhere on the view when it is touched and dragged. Simply the user can re-position the line on the screen. I have no idea how this can be implemented. The line will be drawn with OpenGL ES.

I request all your helps and suggestions regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a second transparent view positioned over the OpenGL view, which acts as a proxy to your line.

Create a clear view (or a view with 0.0001 opacity) and add gesture recognizers to it. Initially place that view (say sized to 44 x 320), and centered over your line (I'm assuming its horizontal). When the user drags the clear view around, post the new position you want your line to appear in within the OpenGL view then tell it to refresh.

I seem to recall (but am unsure) if you can use gesture recognizers with completely clear views - you may need to make the view slightly opaque (but no visibly so) to get touches, but again just not sure.